# StringBuilder Append vs AppendFormat efficiency in C#

Tags: c#

Which is more efficient in C#, 1 or 2?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("my string " + myVar + " my string");     // 1
sb.AppendFormat("my string {0} my string", myVar);  // 2
```

I'm guessing that the question could also be rephrased:

```
string y = "my string " + myVar + " my string";              // 1
string x = String.Format("my string {0} my string", myVar);  // 2
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it?

Comment: You can easily measure this yourself with the Stopwatch class.  Surprise us with a result that shows composite formatting is faster.

Comment: It is true that I could measure this myself but I'm more interested in the why of the answer which I believe is more important than the actual result. I'm guessing that the down votes are because I didn't run the test first and then ask why is one slower than the other...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Version of .NET Framework is important here, because implementation of *StringBuilder.Append* and *StringBuilder.AppendFormat* can differ significantly between individual versions. Under .NET Framework 4, (1) is faster than (2), but it is still inefficient because of overhead caused by concatenating (and thus copying) of (sub)strings. This is even 2x faster than (1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("my string");
sb.Append(myVar);
sb.Append(" my string");
```

**UPDATE**:
Using following test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myVar = "abcdef";
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            //UNCOMMENT ONE OF THESE TESTS
            //Test1
            sb.Append("my string " + myVar + " my string");

            //Test2
            //sb.AppendFormat("my string {0} my string", myVar);

            //Test3
            //sb.Append("my string ");
            //sb.Append(myVar);
            //sb.Append(" my string");
        }
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
}
```

I meassured these results on my computer (Intel Core2 Q9400, Windows Server 2008 x64, .NET Framework 4.0, Release mode):

- Test1: 10401 ms
- Test2: 20262 ms
- Test3: 5771 ms

Comment: Have you measured this? Actually it's not as simple since `String.Concat`(+-operator) also uses `StringBuilder` internally, at least in some overloads(f.e. `Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)`). Furthermore [`String.Intern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) will return known Strings from the system instead of creating new. Nothing is faster than copying a reference. So it's not set in stone(anymore) that a simple string concat  is the slowest.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes, I have measured it. When 3 strings are concatenated, Concat(string, string, string) is called. This method doesn't use StringBuilder, but uses fast method to COPY these substrings to new instance of string returned as result. When appended to StringBuilder, this result is COPIED again to StringBuilder's internal buffer. On the other hand, when you append substrings individually directly to StringBuilder, each string is copied only once.

Comment: @Nuf: Then add the way you've measured it and the results to the answer since it would upvalue it.