# Convert structured List to String

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I want to convert list to string **without linq library** (.Net 3.0).

My list:

```
class child
{
     public string ObjectName { get; set; }
     public string ColorName { get; set; }
}

 List<child> list = new List<child>();

 list.Add(new child { ObjectName = "Value1", ColorName = "Value3" });
 list.Add(new child { ObjectName = "Value4", ColorName = "Value4" });
```

and get result like this:

```
String.Concat(list.Select(o => o.ObjectName + "~" + o.ColorName + "~"));
```

Comment: StringBuilder and foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` class

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var c in list)
     sb.Append(c.ObjectName + "~" + c.ColorName + "~");

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: `AppendFormat` would be better here than string concatenation.

Comment: I thought for simple cases concatenation is better since formating string has a performance penalty.

Comment: For anyone pondering the performance of multiple appends, one concatenated append or one appendformat, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367625/stringbuilder-append-vs-appendformat-efficiency-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `StringBuilder` with [`AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cazfhf32%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (child ch in list)
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}~{1}~", ch.ObjectName, ch.ColorName);
string result = sb.ToString();  // Value1~Value3~Value4~Value4~
```